# Sage Pay Issue Taking 0.10 GBP by default

Tags: reactjs, opayo

Hi can anyone help me on sage pay integration. I am sending the amount 9.99 GBP. But after payment success when we check on sagepay account it is showing payment done is 0.10 GBP. Also deducted amount is 0.10 GBP.

Can you help me on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What integration type are you using with Opayo?

If your using Pi it uses decimalisation

The amount charged to the customer in the smallest currency unit. (e.g 100 pence to charge £1.00, or 1 to charge ¥1 (0-decimal currency).